# IdentifierToken not being hit in Roslyn Analyzer

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm attempting to write a Roslyn analyzer which needs to intercept calls to a function call `WaitForExternalEvent` and perform some logic on the arguments to that function. I have a syntax tree which looks like

[image: Syntax tree]

In code form it looks like

```cs
 public static class HireEmployee
    {
        [FunctionName("HireEmployee")]
        public static async Task<Application> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var applications = context.GetInput<List<Application>>();
            var approvals = await context.WaitForExternalEvent<List<Application>>("ApplicationsFiltered");
            log.LogInformation($"Approval received. {approvals.Count} applicants approved");
            return approvals.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).First();
        }
...
```

When I register the action for this I do so like

```
context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeSyntax, SyntaxKind.IdentifierName);
```

Breakpointing inside my `AnalyzeSyntax` method I do hit breakpoints for IdentifierName tokens but never for the `WaitForExternalEvent` token. Is there some limit to how deep tokens can be? How should I be going about finding these calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to register the action using `SyntaxKind.GenericName` rather than `SyntaxKind.IdentifierName`. Then in your `AnalyzeSyntax` method you want to cast the `context.Node` as a `GenericName` type.

This is what the Syntax Visualizer shows me when I highlight `WaitForExternalEvent<List<Application>>`.

[image]

So, setup the action like this:

```cs
context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeSyntaxNode, SyntaxKind.GenericName);
```

And the start of your method should do this:

```cs
private void AnalyzeSyntaxNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var syntax = context.Node as GenericNameSyntax;
}
```

And I did manage to get it to hit a breakpoint.
[image]